# Make gdb exit on breakpoint

Tags: gdb, breakpoints, exit

I'm using gdb to solve a binary bomb as part of a class. Every time we set the bomb off we lose points. I already have a break point on the function that explodes the bomb, but have accidentally stepped past it a couple times already and exploded the bomb. Is there a way to make gdb exit at a specific point rather than just break?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach commands to breakpoints. After you set breakpoint, e.g. #1, do this:

```
commands 1
quit
end
```